# Jupyter notebook import other .py file with numpy doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter notebook to import another .py file containing my functions. The external function needs numpy module. But when I run, it says "name 'np' is not defined".

I tried to import numpy from my .py file or Jupyter, but it won't work. I don't know what is cause the problem here. Even if I commented on the np import line in the .py file and delete the line which I use the np, the error keeps showing.

In my Jupyter notebook:

```py
import test
import numpy as np
a = np.array([8,3])
m = test.test(a)
```

In test.py:

```
import numpy as np
def test(x):
    m = np.mean(x)
    return m
```

Comment: from test import *

Comment: I kinda fix this. It needs the restart the kernel of the  jupyter notebook after changing the external script.

Answer (score 0):

when ever you made a change on a loaded script at jupyter notebook you should restart the kernel, that what fixes that, even do at the printed log it's shows you the modification you mad but still the error, I think that jupyter community needs to make an update for this bug